# How do I define the article title in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm talking about using the wiki syntax. Normally, I create an article by making a link and then editing it, such as

```
[[secure-auth|Secure 2-Factor Authentication]]
```

But this results in the article being titled "secure-auth" on that page. I want the URL to be foo.com/mywiki/secure-auth , but the article title to be "Secure 2-Factor Authentication".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an article with URL different from the article title. But there are some ways to work around that:

1. Create a [redirect](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aRedirect) from “secure-auth” to “Secure 2-Factor Authentication”.
2. Use [`{{DISPLAYTITLE}}`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words#Technical_metadata) to modify how the page title looks like.
3. Configure your web server (most likely Apache or IIS) to [rewrite the URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) the way you want.